# How to subtract a time literal from a cell value in excel?

Tags: excel

I have the value `42:25:00` in `A1`. I'm looking for the correct formula to calculate

```
A1-41 = 1:25:00
```

I tried

```
=A1-41
```

which gives `############`.

Then I tried

```
=B2-ZEITWERT("41:00:00")
```

which gives `25:15:00`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try with:

`=A1-"41:00:00"`

Regards